# How to aggregate Quote Line data in Steelbrick?

Tags: apex, trigger, limits, aggregate, cpq

I'm trying to determine how to best aggregate data up to the Quote object in Steelbrick CPQ when Quote Lines are added or edited.    Essentially creating rolled up sums of prices for different fields.  This is an advanced Calculator org.

Usually, I would use a rollup summary for this, but we're running up against limits so we need to explore alternatives.  In a non-managed packaged situation, I would usually just go with a trigger to handle this.

The documentation seems to recommend not using triggers on the quote line.  I'm not very fluent in CPQ, but it sounds like this has to do with how they manage the transactions in terms of rolling data back as well as price rules.
[Quote line trigger execution on product selection in QLE](https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/CPQ/Quote-line-trigger-execution-on-product-selection-in-QLE/td-p/13032)

I saw some documentation around the Quote Calculator Plugin, which looked like it might be appropriate, but I'm not clear whether this is automatically invoked or if it is something a user would manually need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For summarizing fields on quote line level to quote, you can use **Summary Variables**.
Look at this [link](https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/Quote-Templates-Knowledge-Base/Adding-Summary-Variables/ta-p/266) and this [link](https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/Prices-Discounts-Knowledge-Base/Summary-Variable-Data-in-Quote-Fields/ta-p/533) to understand summary variables.

Comment: Thanks.  This was helpful and I think it will allow me to pass off responsibility to an administrator  :-)